# Python csv file name as variable

Tags: python, csv, stock

[i am new in python and wondering how i can use filename as variable
I have multiple csv file contain stock price data and files name are timestamp something like this 20171205144050 (time stamp in yyyymmddhhmmss)
now i want to use time as variable in this case 20171205144050
my ultimate goal is to extract stock price and time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErhBM.png)

[image of directory and file formation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOmMT.png)